# Is it possible to initialize a UINavigationController subclass from a NIB?

Tags: cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I have a `UITabBarController` based application. The tabs will be created from database entries, so I don't know them in advance. I'd like to **programmatically** initialize a `UINavigationController` subclass (I have a few different kinds) for each tab.

Ideally, I would really like to draw the whole `UINavigationController` subclass + it's subview using Interface Builder, just like you can do when you add define the view for each tab in IB (that's when you know what the tabs will be in advance). I've tried setting the "Class identity" to my `UINavigationController` subclass name, then add a `UINavigationController` inside it, but obviously it didn't inject the instance at the "File's owner" level...

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've ended up not subclassing `UINavigationController`, it appears it isn't what's recommended. I quickly realized that there wasn't a whole lot of benefit from designing the `UINavigationController`'s from within IB. Instead, I subclassed `UIViewController`, wrote the few lines of init for the`UINavigationBar` (custom buttons, custom middle image) in my `viewDidLoad`. It's just better to simply wrap the subclass with `[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootController: subclass];` when I programmatically fill my tabs. Subclassing  `UINavigationController`directly prevented me from properly using the `navigationItem` property of my inject view.